# Spring Data JPA Repositories with Java 8 Streams detached object?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, java-stream

I do data processing that I can't or don't want to do on the database level, I use streams:

I need to filter users according to some algorithms and then set the name for the users found to database.

```
    userRepository
    .findAll()
    .stream()
    .filter(isFourierTransform())
    .forEach(i ->i.setName("Fourier");
```

Unfortunately, the above code does not save anything to database.

Below the working code

```
List<User>user=userRepository
.findAll()
.stream()
.filter(isFourierTransform())
.collect(Collectors.toList());

for(User user:u)
{
    user.setName("")
}


userRepository.save(user);
```

how to make the first example work?

Comment: Running that code in a `@Transactional` service method should make it work.

Comment: The second variant is fine (besides the fact that you can’t have two variables of the same name). You can replace the loop with `user.forEach(u -> u.setName("Fourier"));` if that makes you feel better.

Answer (score 3):

```
userRepository
  .findAll()
  .stream()
  .filter(isFourierTransform())
  .map(i -> { i.setName("Fourier"); return i;}
  .forEach(userRepository::save)
```

Comment: what about collecting the result in a list and call the repo only once? Would not it be better in terms of performance?

Comment: Using `map` for manipulating on object is not better than `peek`…

Comment: @Holger I always thought that it is somehow "safer", might be a false feeling here. But how would that be done otherwise?

Comment: It’s not safer; there’s no guaranty about the processing order or which elements get processed in the case of a short-circuiting operation and it may get skipped entirely, e.g. when the terminal operation is `count()`, just like with `peek`. And it’s contradicting the intention of the operation, just like with `peek`. You can simply replace the last two operations with `.forEach(u -> { u.setName("Fourier"); userRepository.save(u); });` or even better, stay with the OP’s second variant which is already working and potentially more efficient (by using a single transfer for the entire list).